# Full array length in C

Tags: arrays, c, size

I have a question about getting the length of an array in C.
I always get the result 1.
This result probably comes from the fact, that **int** is 4 bytes big, and 4 / 4 = 1.
So the problem is that I dont get the size of the whole array, only of a single value in it.

Here is my code:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int getArrayLength(int array[]);
>
> int main()
> {
>     int myArray[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
>     printf("Length of array is: %d", getArrayLength(myArray));
>
>     return 0;
> }
>
> int getArrayLength(int array[])
> {
>     int size = (int) sizeof(*array) / sizeof(array[0]);
>     return size;
> }
> ```

Maybe someone can help me fixing my problem.

Thank you^^

Comment: If you make getArrayLength a function, then `array` is a variable in a different scope. It's not possible to get the array size in that function. You should probably make it a preprocessor macro.

Comment: TL;DR for the suggested duplicate (there may be a better one): An array passed as a function argument decays to a pointer.

Comment: Also, can you explain what you think `sizeof(*array)` is and why you would need to divide it by `array[0]`?

Comment: @Cheatah i think he is trying to get byte size of the whole array and divide by the byte value of each position, but yeah, that don't work that way, actually ```*array``` and ```array[0]``` are the same that's why the result its always 1

Comment: Yeah, it did^^
Thank you

Comment: @Cheatah Well, I know that the pointer just points to a single value of the array. Thats why I got 4. But my actual question was, how I can get the size of the full size of the array. But I have already fixed the problem. Thank you^^